# New tax rules for over $600 worth in used items sold on Depop and Ebay tax question

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, ebay

So sadly recently I became unemployed due to funding issues-grant money ran out. Being disabled has me at an increased cost of living compared to a healthy single head of the household person so I started to sell my used old clothing I no longer want since I have the time to post it online. I want to emphasize. I am not profiting. I'm simply trying to get a bit of cash to pay my medical expenses not covered by my insurance.

Naturally with most of the items being over 20 yrs old I don't have receipts. I can't afford a tax expert so if I get that form in the mail from Paypal or Stripe if I reach the $600 limit GROSS, not net mind you-- not actual totals after the fees and shipping, gross, how do I convey on TaxUSA a free tax software, that I did not profit and I'm literally just doing a garage sale to help KEEP MYSELF FROM BEING HOMELESS while I work with Acess-VR to help me get a job as a disabled individual.

I'm having trouble getting employment due to my area of expertise and specific disabilities. SO you can imagine the last thing I want is to report this incorrectly and get taxed if I reach that limit.

The gross total too doesn't take into consideration all the fees I paid and shipping. So really the $500 on my Depop gross after fees I calculated on Excel is only $331 net for the entire year.

I have a business Paypal as I transfer money back and forth and found years ago that's easier to deal with but I'm not a business. So how would I report this since I'm not actually making money, I'm losing money.

Nothing I'm selling IMHO if the IRS saw would flag as being something I'm profiting on. But like every other American I don't save receipts for two blasted decades!!!!! Thank you for your advice I'm not getting any help from Depop even after explaining my calculated Excel sheet and how they shouldn't send out this form to anyone unless they reach net $600 or more on Stripe and naturally Paypal never replies. LOL So yea. At a loss :(.

I can't find a local free tax place in my area that will volunteer to help low income and/or disabled individuals either which do exist in some places.

Comment: You need to report income from sales even if it's less than $600, and even if you don't get any forms about it.

Comment: https://www.cleveland.com/business/2016/06/when_you_have_a_garage_sale_do.html -losses aren't income

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you'll need to decide how you report it. If it's just a sale of personal items, it would probably go on Schedule D.

You then need to determine your cost basis. You start with the fees that you paid for the transaction, and add to it the money you paid to purchase the item. The former is easy, you know it because you just paid it, the latter though is more problematic. You'll need to dig in your records.

If you have any record to prove how much you paid for the item you sold (an old receipt, credit card statement, check or a bank statement with a debit transaction) - you can use it. Otherwise - you're out of luck, and your cost basis is $0 (+transaction fees for the sale).

You then determine your net income, which is your gross proceeds minus the cost basis. If that is negative, you report $0 since you cannot deduct losses on personal items. You'll still list it on your Schedule D to ensure it reconciles with the 1099-K.

As to whether they'll send it to you if you don't reach the $600 threshold - it's up to them. They don't have to, but they're allowed to.

Comment: Schedule D is for capital assets, not personal effects, as per IRS exceptions.

Comment: Why not estimate the FMV. Just keep record. One pair of jeans, purchase est $30, sold $10. (Obviously be realistic. If you buy at old navy, pair of jeans is not $250)

Comment: @paulj you don't need FMV because you know the *actual* V - the amount you sold it for. You cannot "estimate" your purchase price.

Comment: Re schedule D: It's for "*The sale or exchange of a capital asset not reported on another form or schedule*". In this case, proceeds need to be reported somewhere for the 1099-K matching. It can be either Schedule C for business, form 4979 for business assets, or Schedule D for anything else. OP's scenario seems like "anything else" to me.

Comment: Ok so after processing the comments it seems like if I can't pull up receipts, which I can't-99% of what I'm selling I paid cash for in a store off South Street Philly or on an old credit card I cancelled when I was in my late teens/early 20s. But basically if I sub out all fees I paid to list/sell the used item I'd just report THAT number on the Schedule D section so that way when Depop (uses Stripe) reaches $600 gross and I KNOW I only have $350 net I can show I did not earn $600 net after fees and thus its not taxable income? I don't know anyone who sells 20 yr old clothes with receipts TBH

Comment: Also a lot of my stuff I'm selling I also bought from an acquaintance who collects the same brands and we'd buy from eachother and depending upon rarity, the price might be high or retail cost. Like one pair of Lip Service paints I paid $250 for but retail was only $125 ish about....oh, 20 years ago LOL. :P So you see my problem in reporting this if I do reach the gross limit on Stripe which is what Depop uses on their site. Then of course Paypal is another payment option and i'm no where near the $600 limit on Paypal.

Comment: @VanessaWikel The $600 is a red herring, it's just for *their* reporting. You, on your tax return, have to report all the sale transactions whether you get 1099-K or not.

Comment: @littleadv yes but the question is how to report something I already paid taxes on like two decades ago, so I don't get taxed again, that I'm selling for less than what I paid for. I have always found my taxes straight forward and do them myself out of necessity (i.e. can't afford to pay someone to do them for me) that said considering this past year I sold used clothing to help pay for some medical expenses not covered by my insurance, I'm struggling to figure out 'how' to do this so I'm not double taxed, nor violate IRS regulations.

Comment: *"how to report something I already paid taxes on"* - can you prove it? If not - then it didn't happen. I know that's not the answer you wanted.

Answer (score -2):

This is from ebay community. Enter cost of goods equal to what was reported on 1099-k so that amt is zero.

https://community.ebay.com/t5/Selling/What-to-do-About-1099-K-Form-in-quot-Online-Garage-Sale-quot/td-p/29428992/page/2?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=711-53200-19255-0&campid=5337590774&customid=&toolid=10001

https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/state-taxes/discussion/do-i-need-to-file-for-a-1099-k-in-massachusetts-for-garage-type-sales-on-ebay/00/735798

Comment: Answers that are essentially link only tend to rot over time. Please quote the key information in this answer.

Comment: This explains how to "trick" the software into removing the income, but this will not withstand audit and may be considered fraudulent.

Comment: @littleadv Could not say if this would withstand an audit as I am not a tax lawyer, nor an auditor.